# Order of separating Dehn twists in the image of Johnson homomorphisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Let $S$ be a closed surface, $\Gamma=\pi_1 S$ and $\Gamma_i$ be the lower central series defined by $\Gamma_0=\Gamma$ and $\Gamma_i=[\Gamma,\Gamma_{i-1}].$

The Johnson filtration $\lbrace \mathcal{K}_i\rbrace_{i=0,1,\ldots}$ on $\mathrm{Mod}(S)$ is classically defined as the kernels of the maps:
$$\phi_i : \mathrm{Mod}(S) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma/ \Gamma_i).$$
I'm interested in the order of the image of a Dehn twist $\tau_{\gamma}$ along a non-trivial separating curve $\gamma$ on $S$ by the maps $\phi_i.$

I know that the Johnson subgroup (which would be $\mathcal{K}_2$ with these notations) contains all Dehn twists along separating curves, so $\phi_2(\tau_{\gamma})=1.$ My question is:

Is $\phi_3(\tau_{\gamma})$ of infinite order ?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled - do you want the genus to be at least 3? Geoff Mess showed that in genus 2, the Torelli subgroup is freely generated by Dehn twists on separating curves. So I don't think that these lie in the Johnson kernel?

Comment: @IanAgol: In genus $2$, the Johnson homomorphism is $0$ and the Johnson kernel equals the Torelli group.

Comment: The target of the Johnson homomorphism is a torsion-free abelian group, so these are infinite-order if and only if they are nonzero.  And they do indeed map to something nonzero (an explicit formula can be found in one of Morita's papers; I don't have time right now to look up which one, but it is easy enough to work out on your own).